# Upgrading Java runtime for security reasons without recompiling the application with the newer Java version

Tags: java, security, jvm

I have an old web application compiled with Java 5, which for various reasons is not easily upgradeable to a newer version of Java, and which currently runs under Java 5.

My question is whether running the old web application with a newer version of Java (without recompiling the application with the newer Java version and assuming this will not lead to runtime errors) going to mitigate in any significant manner the security risks of the older Java runtime environment?

(I am speaking specifically of security risks related to the older Java runtime environment, I am aware of the fact that passing to a newer Java version will not reduce security risks related to XSS and the like).

Comment: There is no requirement to recompile your software. But if you have difficulties in recompiling it on newer versions, it might be a sign for problems which still occur when running the software. So you should at least do careful testing.

Comment: @Holger I edited the question to make it clear that I ask it with the assumption that there will be no runtime errors (though you are right of course about the need to test the application thoroughly in the case of a newer runtime).

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is best to keep your Java runtime up-to-date. If there are any security risks mitigated by upgrading depends on the application, of course. A "Hello World!" application is likely not to be affected, as it has no security requirements, no attack vectors and doesn't use much runtime components anyway (attack surface).

However, a web application commonly runs on an application server, which will likely use Java for its TLS implementation. That means that it is likely that your TLS implementation has not received an upgrade in years. Although Java has some advantages compared to C thwarting some attacks, other vulnerabilities will certainly be present. For instance, Heartbleed is extremely unlikely to be an issue because it depends on buffer overruns, and Java has internal protection against those. PKCS#1 v1.5 padding oracles are likely to apply because it depends on the actual implementation.

As the Java executable itself is not particularly riddled with easy to exploit bugs, it mainly depends on what functionality is used from the runtime classes of your server, libraries and application (in that order, the server is much more likely to have a large footprint). Upgrade your Java version *and* your server + libraries. Some utility libraries may have less priority depending on their functionality, but stay vigilant. You don't want to have a vulnerability if e.g. Apache Commons Codec has sprung an issue.

Even more important: create an update and upgrade strategy for your system and adhere to it. The amount of testing depends if you have to update or upgrade your system; if well implemented you could go for automated testing for updates and do a full round of testing for upgrades. Hopefully the libraries use semantic versioning so upgrades can be distinguished from updates.

---

If running it on newer versions won't lead to runtime errors depends on the application; it won't if it was build with Java portability in mind, in all likelihood. It is however possible to abuse the Java language to such a degree that it will fail. For instance, I've seen an application crash from one runtime to another that incorrectly implemented `equals` while that element was kept in a list.

For such an old application I think it is time you a full round of testing and possibly a code review to assess if compatibility issues are a topic or not. I've had Java 1.2 apps run without a hitch, but as stated, it depends on how the application was programmed. I'd certainly recompile the classes (where possible) to the latest version, both for compatibility and performance issues.

---

You may first want to migrate to Java 8 before going to Java 11 (both are long term support releases). Java 8 is end of life, but you may want to do a double step because you've been so far behind. Probably that Java 8 version is then just for a short functionality test.

You're probably already need licensing for your Java installation, but I'd make sure that you cover things commercially as well. With Java 8 and 11 there should be a few options worth perusing.

Note that Java 10 onwards is 64 bit only. I've seen 32 bit versions of Java 10 from other vendors, but I'd not upgrade to those as you'll put yourself in another corner to get out of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; regarding Java 8 though, the Wikipedia article cites Oracle: "Oracle will continue to provide Public Updates and auto updates of Java SE 8, until at least the end of December 2020 for Personal Users, and January 2019 for Commercial User". So I don't know whether Java 8 will get any more security updates (I am a "commercial user").

Comment: Yeah, I should have made more clear what I meant there. Updated answer. More chance of breaking something if you take big steps. If too much breaks it may be harder to fix.